# Projector connection via HDMI port shows only home screen background

Tags: 18.04, hdmi, vga, projector

My laptop doesn't have VGA port and while connectiong projector from HDMI port by using HDMI to VGA cable the projector only shows the background of the home screen. I've tried both mirror and extended display options but i cannot solve my problem. Please suggest me what to do thank you in advance.

Comment: Mirror - same output for both monitors (the projector acts as a second monitor) - is the mode you want but also you may need to adjust the resulution to the maximum allowed by the projector, often less than what a modern monitor supports. And a projector with only VGA is certainly old or very old and is likely to support only very low resolution.

Comment: Thank you i will try with newer version of projector.